# Accessing UserControl Name property in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF UserControl named YesNoSelection, containing a Label and two RadioButtons named rbnYes and rbnNo. I would like to Automatically set the RadioButton GroupName property to the name of my control, so I used:

```
public YesNoSelection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            rbnYes.GroupName = this.Name;
            rbnNo.GroupName = this.Name;
        }
```

The control is added in designer like this:

```
<local:YesNoSelection x:Name="selOnTop" Label="Always on top" Margin="2,2,2,2" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

However, it does not work. After some debugging, I found that

```
this.Name
```

always returns empty. In the designer, it does not let me set the regular Name property, just x:Name, because the class is defined locally (I think?).

I have done a lot of work in WinForms, but am quite new to WPF. Is there any way to achieve this? Or maybe another way to achieve the UserControl assigning a unique GroupName to the RadioButtons without seting any other properties? I know I could set them manually, or create another property and use that, but I would like to know if this is possible or not.

To summarize, my goal is to have a UserControl with two RadioButtons, which automatically get their GroupName assigned to their parent YesNoSelection Name.

Comment: "this" refers to the window. Have you tried just referencing it as "selOnTop" ?

Comment: @TerryTyson No, `this` in a YesNoSelection constructor references the currently created YesNoSelection instance.

Comment: Be aware that the Name property is *not yet set* in the constructor. It is set *later*. Consider overriding the OnInitialized method or attach a Loaded event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so based on Clemens' advice, I tried both overriding OnInitialized and using the Loaded event. Overriding OnInitialized yielded the same result, but the Loaded event did the trick. So the correct code in this case is

```
public YesNoSelection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
  
            this.Loaded += YesNoSelection_Loaded;   
        }
    
private void YesNoSelection_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            rbnYes.GroupName = this.Name;
            rbnNo.GroupName = this.Name;
        }
```

Many thanks to Clemens for the solution!

Comment: I have not found a good diagram of the life cycle events of WPF controls. But this article at least describes them in detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/object-lifetime-events?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8